# How should I design my application so that it is easy to offer multiple languages?

Tags: php, javascript, internationalization

I am currently building an web app using mostly PHP and JavaScript. What is the best way to design an app so that it is easy to make it available in multiple languages? Originally it will only be in English but I may want to make it available in other languages in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100 percent sure this answers your question, but here's a post on internationalization and localization in PHP to get you started : http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/php/2002/11/28/php_i18n.html.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [built-in feature](http://devzone.zend.com/article/4799) starting with PHP 5.3 that handles i18n.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to do multi language support I recommend using [GETTEXT](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php), it seems to be the best solution for this, I am planning to do it in my app!

Answer (score 1):

If JavaScript is involved, try this: http://www.zomeoff.com/jsin/